# How to use array of objects in golang template?

Tags: html, go, templates

I have an array of `products`. Here is my `HomeHandler` method where gets the list of products and send it to the `home.html`.

```
func (f *FrontendServer) HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, h *http.Request) {
    products := ListProducts()
    parsedTemplate, _ := template.ParseFiles("templates/home.html")
    fmt.Printf("type of product %T\n", products)
    fmt.Println("PRODUCTS\n", products)
    err := parsedTemplate.Execute(w, products)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error executing template:", err)
    }
}
```

This is my `home.html` file.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>First Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/home.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <ul>
    {{range .products}}
    <li>
      {{$.name}}
    </li>
     {{end}}
  </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried bunch of techniques like `$.Products`, `.Products`, etc. It gives me an error all the time when I make a request to the homepage as below:

```
2021/05/17 00:19:26 Error executing template:template: home.html:9:12: executing "home.html" at <.products>: can't evaluate field products in type []main.Product
```

When I print the products its type is as below.

```
[{1001 Product 1 A product 12.99} {1002 Product 2 A product 13.99} {1003 Product 3 A product 14.99} {1004 Product 4 A product 15.99} {1005 Product 5 A product 16.99} {1006 Product 6 A product 18.99} {1007 Product 7 A product 19.99} {1008 Product 8 A product 20.99} {1009 Product 9 A product 21.99} {1010 Product 1 A product 22.99}]
```

And here is my Product struct:

```
type Product struct {
    ID          int     `json:"product_id"`
    Name        string  `json:"product_name"`
    Description string  `json:"product_description"`
    Price       float32 `json:"product_price"`
}
```

I want to list all products in `<li>` tags. How can I iterate through all items in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
{{range .products}}
```

looks for a variable named `products` in `.`, where `.` is the current context, which, at the top level, is the argument to `Execute`. Based on the error, you are already passing a products array. So, do one of the following:

Either:

```
{{range .}}
```

which means, range over the `products` array passed to `Execute`, or

```
    err := parsedTemplate.Execute(w, map[string]interface{}{"products":products})
```

This will create a map containing `products`, which is an array, so `{{range .products}}` will work.

Comment: Also, just to add to your answer Burak, inside the range it should be `{{.Name}}` and not `{{$.name}}` as baris attempts. Case matters and `$.` is the root context, not the iteration variable.